# Extracting value from a Pandas column that is a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a Dataframe in the below format:

```
id, value
101, [{'id': 'ZWJ', 'type': 'user_reference', 'summary': 'Person 1'}]
102, [{'id': 'ZWS', 'type': 'user_reference', 'summary': 'Person 2'}]
```

I am trying to extract the value tagged to summary in each row.

Expected output :

```
id, name
101, Person 1
102, Person 2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expand nested list of dictionaries in a pandas dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55093729/expand-nested-list-of-dictionaries-in-a-pandas-dataframe-column) or [Convert list of dictionaries to a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638006/convert-list-of-dictionaries-to-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str[0]` for get first list and then [`Series.str.get`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html) for value `summary`:

```
df['name'] = df['value'].str[0].str.get('summary')

print (df)
    id                                              value      name
0  101  [{'id': 'ZWJ', 'type': 'user_reference', 'summ...  Person 1
1  102  [{'id': 'ZWS', 'type': 'user_reference', 'summ...  Person 2
```

**Details**:

```
print (df['value'].str[0])
0    {'id': 'ZWJ', 'type': 'user_reference', 'summa...
1    {'id': 'ZWS', 'type': 'user_reference', 'summa...
Name: value, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Got this fixed by

```
df['name'] = df.value(operator.itemgetter(0)).apply(operator.itemgetter('summary'))
```